# 5.1 Channels with PortAudio

Tags: alsa, portaudio, surround

I am trying to get started with PortAudio.  I am able to build the bundled example file "paex_sine.c" with no problems.  This a sine wave on the left channel and a different frequency sine wave on the right channel.  This works properly with no errors.

My setup is a 32-bit PC running Puppy Linux Slacko 5.5.  It has a SoundBlaster SB0200 with EMU10k1x chip.  The Alsa library is v1.0.26, and driver is v1.0.24.  I have tested all 5.1 channels using this command:

```
% speaker-test -Dplug:surround51 -c6
```

The test plays sound properly on each of the 6 channels, though it does complain about broken pipes.  This is probably because the buffer is not large enough in the test program for all 6 channels.

The issue that I am having is that when I modify "paex_sine.c" to run on 6 channels instead of just 2, it will only play sound through the front-right and front-left channels.  There are no errors reported, and the 2 channels sound like they should.  I have heard that channels must be unmuted in some cases.  In AlsaMixer and Puppy's "Retrovol" (which mirrors AlsaMixer), I have set Master, PCM, and Surround to max volume, unmuted.  Could there be a mixer in PortAudio that I also have to unmute?  I can go back and forth between running speaker-test properly and running the modified paex_sine example and hearing only 2 channels.  Here is paex_sine.c that I have modified:

```
    /** @file paex_sine.c
        @ingroup examples_src
        @brief Play a sine wave for several seconds.
        @author Ross Bencina <rossb@audiomulch.com>
        @author Phil Burk <philburk@softsynth.com>
    */
    /*
     * $Id: paex_sine.c 1752 2011-09-08 03:21:55Z philburk $
     *
     * This program uses the PortAudio Portable Audio Library.
     * For more information see: http://www.portaudio.com/
     * Copyright (c) 1999-2000 Ross Bencina and Phil Burk
     *
     * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
     * a copy of this software and associated documentation files
     * (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction,
     * including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge,
     * publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software,
     * and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so,
     * subject to the following conditions:
     *
     * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
     * included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
     *
     * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
     * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
     * MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
     * IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR
     * ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF
     * CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
     * WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
     */

    /*
     * The text above constitutes the entire PortAudio license; however, 
     * the PortAudio community also makes the following non-binding requests:
     *
     * Any person wishing to distribute modifications to the Software is
     * requested to send the modifications to the original developer so that
     * they can be incorporated into the canonical version. It is also 
     * requested that these non-binding requests be included along with the 
     * license above.
     */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include "portaudio.h"

    #define NUM_SECONDS   (30)
    #define SAMPLE_RATE   (44100)
    #define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER  (192)//(64)

    #ifndef M_PI
    #define M_PI  (3.14159265)
    #endif

    #define TABLE_SIZE   (200)
    typedef struct
    {
        float sine[TABLE_SIZE];
        int left_phase;
        int right_phase;
        int left2_phase;
        int right2_phase;
        int left3_phase;
        int right3_phase;
        char message[20];
    }
    paTestData;

    /* This routine will be called by the PortAudio engine when audio is needed.
    ** It may called at interrupt level on some machines so don't do anything
    ** that could mess up the system like calling malloc() or free().
    */
    static int patestCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                                unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                                const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                                PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                                void *userData )
    {
        paTestData *data = (paTestData*)userData;
        float *out = (float*)outputBuffer;
        unsigned long i;

        (void) timeInfo; /* Prevent unused variable warnings. */
        (void) statusFlags;
        (void) inputBuffer;

        for( i=0; i<framesPerBuffer; i++ )
        {
            *out++ = data->sine[data->left_phase];  /* left */
            *out++ = data->sine[data->right_phase];  /* right */
            *out++ = data->sine[data->left2_phase];  /* left */
            *out++ = data->sine[data->right2_phase];  /* right */
            *out++ = data->sine[data->left3_phase];  /* left */
            *out++ = data->sine[data->right3_phase];  /* right */
            data->left_phase += 1;
            if( data->left_phase >= TABLE_SIZE ) data->left_phase -= TABLE_SIZE;
            data->right_phase += 3; /* higher pitch so we can distinguish left and right. */
            if( data->right_phase >= TABLE_SIZE ) data->right_phase -= TABLE_SIZE;
            data->left2_phase += 5;
            if( data->left2_phase >= TABLE_SIZE ) data->left2_phase -= TABLE_SIZE;
            data->right2_phase += 7; /* higher pitch so we can distinguish left and right. */
            if( data->right2_phase >= TABLE_SIZE ) data->right2_phase -= TABLE_SIZE;
            data->left3_phase += 9;
            if( data->left3_phase >= TABLE_SIZE ) data->left3_phase -= TABLE_SIZE;
            data->right3_phase += 11; /* higher pitch so we can distinguish left and right. */
            if( data->right3_phase >= TABLE_SIZE ) data->right3_phase -= TABLE_SIZE;
        }

        return paContinue;
    }

    /*
     * This routine is called by portaudio when playback is done.
     */
    static void StreamFinished( void* userData )
    {
       paTestData *data = (paTestData *) userData;
       printf( "Stream Completed: %s\n", data->message );
    }

    /*******************************************************************/
    int main(void);
    int main(void)
    {
        PaStreamParameters outputParameters;
        PaStream *stream;
        PaError err;
        paTestData data;
        int i;


        printf("PortAudio Test: output sine wave. SR = %d, BufSize = %d\n", SAMPLE_RATE, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER);

        /* initialise sinusoidal wavetable */
        for( i=0; i<TABLE_SIZE; i++ )
        {
            data.sine[i] = (float) sin( ((double)i/(double)TABLE_SIZE) * M_PI * 2. );
        }
        data.left_phase = data.right_phase = 0;
        data.left2_phase = data.right2_phase = 0;
        data.left3_phase = data.right3_phase = 0;

        err = Pa_Initialize();
        if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

        outputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice(); /* default output device */
        if (outputParameters.device == paNoDevice) {
          fprintf(stderr,"Error: No default output device.\n");
          goto error;
        }
        outputParameters.channelCount = 6;       /* 5.1 Channel Output */
        outputParameters.sampleFormat = paFloat32; /* 32 bit floating point output */
        outputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( outputParameters.device )->defaultLowOutputLatency;
        outputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

        err = Pa_OpenStream(
                  &stream,
                  NULL, /* no input */
                  &outputParameters,
                  SAMPLE_RATE,
                  FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
                  paClipOff,      /* we won't output out of range samples so don't bother clipping them */
                  patestCallback,
                  &data );
        if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

        sprintf( data.message, "No Message" );
        err = Pa_SetStreamFinishedCallback( stream, &StreamFinished );
        if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

        err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
        if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

        printf("Play for %d seconds.\n", NUM_SECONDS );
        Pa_Sleep( NUM_SECONDS * 1000 );

        err = Pa_StopStream( stream );
        if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

        err = Pa_CloseStream( stream );
        if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

        Pa_Terminate();
        printf("Test finished.\n");

        return err;
    error:
        Pa_Terminate();
        fprintf( stderr, "An error occured while using the portaudio stream\n" );
        fprintf( stderr, "Error number: %d\n", err );
        fprintf( stderr, "Error message: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText( err ) );
        return err;
    }
```

Comment: What is the device info's `maxOutputChannels`?

Comment: maxOutputChannels = 128

Comment: In the speaker-test command, if I skip the -Dplug:surround51 switch, it behaves the same way - only front-left and front-right make sound, even though I have still specified 6 channels.

Comment: If I run the "pa_devs" example, this prints out device indexes and corresponding names.  In my modified example program (posted originally), if I force outputParameters.device to the index with name "surround51" (10), max channels is then reported as 6, but then the example chokes and complains about an invalid sample rate.

Answer (score 2):

Without the `plug:`, there will be no automatic resampling.

PortAudio does not allow to set your own device name, so you would have to define you own device in `~/.asoundrc` or `/etc/asound.conf`, like this:

```perl
pcm.mydevice = "plug:surround51"
```

and select that in PortAudio (search for it with `Pa_GetDeviceCount`/`Pa_GetDeviceInfo`).
Alternatively, make it the default device with:

```perl
pcm.!default = "plug:surround51"
```

Comment: I am not familiar with this type of file.  How can I adapt this example:

pcm.card0 {
    type hw
    card 0
}
ctl.card0 {
    type hw
    card 0
}

Do I just tack this onto the end of the file?:

pcm.card0 = "plug:surround51"

Comment: Replace the original `pcm.card0` definition.

Comment: None of these (A, B, C below) make any difference, max channels still = 128, still only front-right and front-left make sound.  I am now using "patest_multi_sine" because it should play on all speakers without modification.  [[[A]]]  pcm.card0 = "plug:surround51" ctl.card0 { type hw card 0 }  [[[B]]]  pcm.card0 { plug surround51 } ctl.card0 { type hw card 0 }  [[[C]]]  pcm.card0 { type hw card 0 plug surround51 } ctl.card0 { type hw card 0 }

Comment: The syntax of B and C is wrong. Did you select the `card0` device?

Comment: How do I select the card0 device?  In the source file, I am using outputParameters.device=Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice(), which is expecting a number.  Is there a way to change the default device?  Please understand that I am very new to this and I have basically no clue what I'm doing - I appreciate your patience.

Comment: I added this line to .asoundrc: pcm.!default surround51:Live  This had the same effect as forcing outputParameters.device to the index with name "surround51" (10).  It reports 6 channels, then it gives an error message: invalid sample rate, error number -9997.

Comment: After adding pcm.!default surround51:Live to .asoundrc, % speaker-test -c6 now works on all 6 channels without the -Dplug:surround51 switch.

Comment: I want to be clear that, though there is some success with speaker-test, the PortAudio examples still have the invalid sample rate error seen earlier.  Does anyone have a suggestion that I could try?  I am out of ideas.  I appreciate your help so far, CL - we've made some real progress.

Comment: I just repeated the whole thing with an SiS SI7012 5.1 channel sound card with similar results.  speaker-test -c6 worked without broken pipes on all channels, but the PortAudio examples still did not work on more than 2 channels.  I tried removing .asoundrc and changing the contents to suit the new card.  This does not appear to be a common issue with PortAudio, so I'm starting to suspect something is funky with Puppy Linux.  This is a fresh install.  I may try a different Linux and see what happens.

Comment: Forgot to mention, invalid sample rate is still reported on the SiS when 5.1 mode is specified in .asoundrc when I run the PortAudio examples.

Comment: Thanks for that, @CL. - I was wandering how to set the default PortAudio device in Linux, your suggestion works. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I changed my ~/.asoundrc to:

```
pcm.!default plug:surround51:Live
```

And that fixed the issue.